# My comment(replies) to other user were deleted

Tags: discussion

I have a question about my Super User post: [Recovering Windows 11](https://superuser.com/questions/1721927/recovering-windows-11)

My comment(replies) to other user were deleted. They didn't violate any rules and they were on topic and valid replies to the user. Why were they deleted?

Answer (score 3):

Well - the first one had nothing to do with the question at all

> @ChanganAuto I didn't select that username, it was automatically given to me, because there was a problem with registration on stackexchange. After typing in my details and clicking confirm, I wasn't getting next page showing me to click on emailed link, instead I was getting an option to recover my non-existent account, so I typed my email(which is not registered with stackexchange) and it gave that username. And why should I justify my username, etc, how many here or elsewhere do that? I forgot that I had an account on stackexchange. As I didn't use it 6 months. –

The second, while a reply didn't have much value.

Comments are not spaces for conversation, they're a place for clarifications, and comments are transient and deleted when no longer needed. These didn't really help get closer to a solution.

Comment: Both of them had value, if my comments didn't have value, neither does changanauto's nor does your opinion about they not containing value. All comments don't have to contain relevant content related to the question. There is something else you are too ashamed to admit to yourselves, which caused you to delete this.

Comment: Does ChanganAuto's comment get closer to the solution? I've seen so many questions on stackexchange, tons of comments hardly have any relevance to the questions but still they are left, I don't this aggressive and regressive moderation there, what did my comments have which compelled the moderators to delete them?

Comment: @linuxtroubleshooting - You are absolutely correct, none of the comments submitted under the answer to your question, are helpful so I flagged all of them as “no longer necessary”. Your question needs some work, might want to work on that…

Comment: @Ramhound Thanks, I'll work on it.